# How to find what apps are being launched automatically

Tags: linux

I've installed several tools such as MySQL, RabbitMQ, PHP and several others.

I realized that these are all being launched every time I start my computer.

Where can I find a list of these apps so I can disable them from starting automatically?

I am using Linux.

Comment: `service --status-all` will give you a list, they in `/etc/init.d`

Comment: also `systemctl --type=service`

Comment: Thank you for your response @LawrenceCherone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, this kind of long-running service is mostly run through `systemd`. You can see all running services with `systemctl status`, giving you a nice output showing everythong running in systemd.

You can also use `sudo systemctl list-unit-files -t service | grep enabled` to find all service units that are enabled (some may be enabled but failed to start, for example). The second column is whether it's enabled now, the third is whether it is enabled by default or was enabled through some other mean.

Keep in mind some of the services in the output of these commands are parts of systemd or important parts of your system - you should take care when disabling services you don't recognize.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details about the listing.